# Complex nested time-series ARIMA mode

Tags: arima, panel-data, hidden-markov-model, quantile-regression

This question has to do with the underlying statistical methodology. I have some expert knowledge of the domain but I am not certain the method I want to use is statistically sound. Let's assume that data quantity and quality is not a problem and there is no seasonality. Please let me explain the details:

I have a variable which I want to forecast for up to t+5:

```
Y
```

This variable is of an "unbalanced panel" nature, that is I have 100's of overlapping observations over the same periods and the variable differs substantially at most levels with some missing values. So, for level 1 it could be bound between [5, 100] and level 2 could be between [10,50]. The levels are not strongly correlated.

I use an ARIMA model to provide forecasts using the auto.arima function in R to account for the particularities of each "level" of the panel. After the fitted values are generated, I will have residuals for the time series for all those panel levels. I will also be able to forecast for n.ahead = 5 for Y.

However, I also know that factually my dependent variable Y has externalities, that is, it is certainly impacted by exogenous variables for which I **will have** the t+5 forecasts :

```
X1, ... , X10
```

The obvious choice would be the ARIMAX extension but I have shown that the performance gets substantially worse if any additional regressors are included to generate a time-series model with ARIMAX errors.

I need to incorporate those X1, ... , X10 external regressors into the t+5 forecasts as "impulses" or changes of the level of the

```
Y
```

but retaining the performance of the "simple" ARIMA model.

There are two methods that I am contemplating:

1. Build a quantile regression

Use the residuals of the ARIMA model to create a distribution of each panel level, and then build a quantile regression of the residuals against the exogenous variables (X1 to X10) so that I can map the impact of the exogenous variables to the forecasted values through the ARIMA model. So if the external regressors "point" to a 5% quantile I would (hopefully) subtract a value from the forecasted value to get a value that is "impacted" by those regressors for t+k.

2. Build a panel regression of the residuals

If these residuals truly carry information and are not white noise, then these external regressors, would, at least partially, dictate the level of the residual. So using an unbalanced panel regression, I could capture the level.

So, irrespective of 1 or 2, I would simply substract the impulse generated by those methods to the forecasted Y variable.

Is this model approach rational? Does it breach any statistical assumptions?

I know that ultimately out-of-sample performance dictates what the model design should look like, but I am appealing to the experience of readers. I also believe that due to the complexity a (non closed-form) simulations-based or markov-chain approach might work. Please provide any references you think are appropriate.

Thank you